# PDF Type Detection

Tags: python

How to recognize a pdf within training data set whether it is electronic or scanned in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the PDF to HTML format using [PDFMiner](https://github.com/euske/pdfminer/).
Then you can use [beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to find if it contains only `<img>` tag then it's totally a scanned PDF, otherwise, if any text data found then it is electronic.
Moreover, you can decide this based on the percentage of text extracted.

Comment: I believe your assertion that all PDFs resulting in a single `<img>` tag will be necessarily be from scanned images.